# REALIZAR UN SISTEMA CON CICLO PARA, MIENTRAS Y REPETIR

Tags: pseint

alguien que me ayude con un ejercicio en PSeInt porfavor, se lo agradecería:
En un colegio se desea realizar un sistema que permita solicitar un numero a cada estudiante y mostrar la sumatoria de sus digitos (el numero ingresado debe tener 5 digitos)

Comment: Aquí no hacemos eso. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Te seré muy sincero, no estoy a favor de esto de hacer tareas, trata de esforzarte un poco, te dejo una solución con el ciclo para, que tiende a ser uno de los más complejos de comprender en Pseint, te queda a ti hacer los demás, saludos.

```
Algoritmo sumatoria
  Definir num, sumaTotal, cantEstudiantes, contador Como Enteros;
  sumaTotal <- 0;
  Escribir "Ingrese la cantidad de estudiantes";
  Leer cantEstudiantes;
  Para contador <- 1 Hasta cantEstudiantes Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Repetir
      Escribir "Estudiante ", contador, " ingrese un número";
      Leer num;
      Si (num < 9999 o num > 99999) Entonces
        Escribir "Número no valido";
      FinSi
    Hasta Que num > 9999 y num <= 99999
    sumaTotal <- sumaTotal + num;
  FinPara
  Escribir "La suma total es: ", sumaTotal;
FinAlgoritmo
```